# Dependent options in docopt

Tags: python, docopt

I was wondering if I could have dependent options in docopt.

example:

```
"""
Description:
  Flash a system with the manufacturing software from the specifiedx folder.

Usage:
  flash_drop.py (--drop-dir=<DIR>) [--factory-reset=<BOOL>] [--flash-all=<BOOL>] [--flash-system1=<BOOL> | --flash-system2=<BOOL>]
  flash_drop.py -h | --help
  flash_drop.py --version

Options:
  -h --help                 Show this screen.
  --version                 Show version.
  --drop-dir=DIR            Path to the drop directory
  --factory-reset=BOOL          Factory reset the chips on all selected devices. [default: False]
  --flash-all=BOOL              Flash all devices. [default: False]
  --flash-system1=BOOL          Flash first system. [default: False]
  --flash-system2=BOOL          Flash second system. [default: False]
"""
```

Namely, the value of an option is ignored if a previous option hasn't been selected. So for instance, the value for `--flash-system2` is ignored unless `--flash-system1` is set

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible to modify the code you can ignore them programmatically for example:

```py
args['flash-system2'] = args['flash-system2'] if args['flash-system1'] else None
```

or

```py
if ('flash-system2' in args) and ('flash-system1' not in args):
    del args['flash-system2']
```

just after parsing the arguments

Comment: I'm doing it like that for now, but I was just wondering, if docopt had a functionality like this.

Comment: not as far as I know. there isn't a functionality as such. It would be cool, however, if we can say to the user you can't specify `flash-system2` if `flash-system1` is not given without having to write it.

Answer (score 0):

Not with a single usage pattern, but you can do it with 2 patterns:

```
Usage:
  flash_drop.py (--drop-dir=<DIR>) [options] [--flash-system1=<BOOL>]
  flash_drop.py (--drop-dir=<DIR>) [options] --flash-system1=<BOOL> --flash-system2=<BOOL>
```

But probably better with three pattern, easier to read IMO:

```
Usage:
  flash_drop.py (--drop-dir=<DIR>) [options]
  flash_drop.py (--drop-dir=<DIR>) [options] --flash-system1=<BOOL>
  flash_drop.py (--drop-dir=<DIR>) [options] --flash-system1=<BOOL> --flash-system2=<BOOL>
  flash_drop.py -h | --help
  flash_drop.py --version
```

[Live demo](http://try.docopt.org/?doc=Description%3A%0D%0A++Flash+a+system+with+the+manufacturing+software+from+the+specifiedx+folder.%0D%0A%0D%0AUsage%3A%0D%0A++flash_drop.py+%28--drop-dir%3D%3CDIR%3E%29+%5Boptions%5D%0D%0A++flash_drop.py+%28--drop-dir%3D%3CDIR%3E%29+%5Boptions%5D+--flash-system1%3D%3CBOOL%3E%0D%0A++flash_drop.py+%28--drop-dir%3D%3CDIR%3E%29+%5Boptions%5D+--flash-system1%3D%3CBOOL%3E+--flash-system2%3D%3CBOOL%3E%0D%0A++flash_drop.py+-h+%7C+--help%0D%0A++flash_drop.py+--version%0D%0A%0D%0AOptions%3A%0D%0A++-h+--help+++++++++++++++++Show+this+screen.%0D%0A++--version+++++++++++++++++Show+version.%0D%0A++--drop-dir%3DDIR++++++++++++Path+to+the+drop+directory%0D%0A++--factory-reset%3DBOOL++++++++++Factory+reset+the+chips+on+all+selected+devices.+%5Bdefault%3A+False%5D%0D%0A++--flash-all%3DBOOL++++++++++++++Flash+all+devices.+%5Bdefault%3A+False%5D%0D%0A++--flash-system1%3DBOOL++++++++++Flash+first+system.+%5Bdefault%3A+False%5D%0D%0A++--flash-system2%3DBOOL++++++++++Flash+second+system.+%5Bdefault%3A+False%5D&argv=--drop-dir%3DDDD+--factory-reset%3Dtrue+--flash-system1%3Dtrue+--flash-system2%3Dtrue)

---

P.S.

Well, you *can*, *technically*, do it with a single pattern, but it starts to get really long...

```
Usage:
  flash_drop.py (--drop-dir=<DIR>) [options] [(--flash-system1=<BOOL>) | (--flash-system1=<BOOL> --flash-system2=<BOOL>)]
```

Lines can be broken, so maybe:

```
Usage:
  flash_drop.py (--drop-dir=<DIR>) [options] 
                [(--flash-system1=<BOOL>) | (--flash-system1=<BOOL> --flash-system2=<BOOL>)]
```

Personally I prefer the 3-pattern solution.